# Calling Enumerable.Join on a IEnumerable collection causes segmentation fault

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have a class Person:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Surname {get; set;}
    public uint Age {get; set;}

    public Person(string name, string surname, uint age)
    {
        Name= name; 
        Surname= surname;
        Age= age;
    }
    public Person() : this("default","default",25) {}
}
```

And a class People which holds a collection of Person objects:

```
public class People : IEnumerable<Person>
{
    private List<Person> people= new List<Person> ();
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        people.GetEnumerator();
    }
    public IEnumerator<Person> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
    public void Add(Person p)
    {
        people.Add(p);
    }
}
```

Now I wanted to try making a LINQ join query, which tries to group persons with the same Name property, creating a new anonymous object which hold the name, and both the surnames (Surname1, Surname2):

```
People ppl1 = new People() {
                new Person(),
                new Person("Mario","",35),
                new Person("Garcya","Luis",32)
            };
People ppl2 = new People() {
                new Person(),
                new Person("Pablo","Escobar",82),
                new Person("Claudio","Sevilla",33),
                new Person("Garcya","",31)
            };
var commonPpl=ppl1.Join<Person, Person, string, object>(ppl2, p => p.Name, p => p.Name,
                (p1, p2) => new { Name = p1.Name, Surname1 = p1.Surname, Surname2 = p2.Surname });
```

Now the problem is that if I execute this query I get a segmentation fault: GetEnumerator() gets called infinitely until the stack is full.

Comment: Get rid of these methods System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        people.GetEnumerator();
    }
    public IEnumerator<Person> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

Comment: I edited the question because the title, and the workaround (which was wrong, it didn't work either) were misleading.

Comment: Note that the code you've presented wouldn't even compile. I suspect your real code has a `return` statement in the explicit interface implementation. If you edit your question to fix that, I'll remove that point from my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So I can imagine that Linq is calling GetEnumerator() many times

No, that's not the case. The problem is in your implementation of `IEnumerable`, notably here:

```
public IEnumerator<Person> GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```

That method is recursive. You're probably *expecting* it to call the explicit interface implementation, but it's not - it's just recursing.

Typically, you make the explicit interface implementation call the public method:

```
System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    // Call the public method. The body of this method wasn't even valid before,
    // as it was calling `people.GetEnumerator() but not returning anything.
    return GetEnumerator();
}

public IEnumerator<Person> GetEnumerator()
{
    return people.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Basically, you'd have seen the same effect if you'd just used a normal `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var person in people)
{
    // You'd never get this far
}
```

It has nothing to do with LINQ.

Comment: I noticed it before editing the question. Truly it was a mistake, the solution that I posted didn't work either.

Comment: @Ramy: No, your workaround wouldn't have worked bexause LINQ wasn't calling that method.